# How to fix django channels consumers stopping to handle messages send to groups

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, daphne

Sending messages to groups using `group_send()` suddenly stops working after some time. The handler method of the consumer is not called anymore.

Restarting `daphne` is fixing the issue for some time.

**Details**

There is no error showing up anywhere in the logs, just the messages are not getting handled by the consumers anymore.

I'm, using the following libraries:

- aioredis==1.2.0
- asgiref==2.3.2
- channels-redis==2.3.2
- channels==2.1.6
- daphne==2.2.4
- django==2.1.5
- redis==3.0.1

**Code**

```py
# settings.py
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {"hosts": [("localhost", "6379")]},
    }
}
```

```py
# views.py
class ReceiveEventView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # payload: {"type": "event_triggered", "group": "warning", "message": "Button pressed"}
        # or
        # payload: {"type": "event_triggered", "group": "danger", "message": "Red Button pressed"}
        payload = json.loads(request.POST.get("payload", "{}"))
        if (payload.get("type") == "event_triggered"):
            async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(payload.get("group"), payload)
        return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

```py
# consumers.py
class EventConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self):
        if not self.scope["user"].is_authenticated:
            return
        self.accept()
        for group in get_subscriptions(self.scope["user"]):
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(group, self.channel_name)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        if not self.scope["user"].is_authenticated:
            return
        for group in get_subscriptions(self.scope["user"]):
            async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)(group, self.channel_name)

    def event_triggered(self, event):
        logger.debug("Consumer::event_triggered()")
        self.send(text_data=json.dumps(event))
```

**expected and actual results**

For some time `Consumer::event_triggered()` appears in the logging, but suddenly stops. Receiving messages from the browser via WebSocket still works. Just the transport from `group_send()` to the consumers is broken.

Comment: Which version of Python do you use? 3.5.2? there seems to be a known bug with the combination of [this version and channels](https://github.com/django/channels_redis/issues/79)

Comment: I'm using Python 3.5.3

Comment: I've compiled Python 3.6.8 and will have a look at it. Hopefully it will run without issues until tomorrow. Thanks for the hint regarding the Python version.

Comment: Great, I have posted it as an answer, If that works, don't forget to accept the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [known bug](https://github.com/django/channels_redis/issues/79) causing a break up in connections after a while for Channels apps running in Python 3.5. Update to Python 3.6 for a possible fix

Comment: Thanks again for your help. It was indeed an issue with Python 3.5. Running my application with Python 3.6 is not showing this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue with Python3.8. So I fixed it by switching to Python3.6

[Django channels - Client receives message sometimes and not other times till it doesn't recieve it at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63225354/django-channels-client-receives-message-sometimes-and-not-other-times-till-it/63242093#63242093)

Comment: yes! me too, I tried also python3.9 but it has the same problem. I fixed switching to python3.6